# JQuery making an object of all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, object, checkbox, filter

I have a site on which there's few links(hrefs) and each of those links is showing a set of inputs type=checkbox (which are generated from the backened), when you click on a link it shows lets say 10 of inputs, other ones become display:none;(on load there's just an initial set of those checkboxes by default) and with jquery i've made so you could just toggle which checkboxes you want to see.

Now i need to make an object in which i can put everything that's checked, their names and values, so when i click on a button i can send it to the backend via ajax.

The function wich calls ajax "and gets values and names is":

```
function Bada() {

    var obj = $('.custom input[type="checkbox"]');


    var checkedCount =  obj.filter(':checked').length;
    var checkedInputs = obj.filter(':checked');
    console.log('The console is working');
    for(check in checkedInputs){
        console.log(checkedInputs[check].name);
        console.log(checkedInputs[check].value);
    } 
    delete window.checkedInputs;
    delete window.obj;

             $.ajax({
                 url: "/getItems",
                 type: "post",
                 data : { form: childCount, count: checkedCount },
                 success:  function(responseText){

                     alert('works');

                 }
             })
             //unfocus the button after the call to server, otherwise the marker stays in the text of the button as if that text is selected
             $('.button').blur();

    }
```

The problem i'm having is as follows:
when the page loads and there's those initial checkboxes on view(other one's in display:none;), everything works, i get a name of checkbox and the values,
but as soon, as i click on a link and it sets on display other set of checkboxes and puts the previous ones in display:none;, when i click the button again, instead of getting the names and/or values of checked checkboxes it displays all of the previous checkboxes (checked and unchecked, the whole list of them, which was previously **and the current ones shown as well** , but totally ignores if anything's checked or unchecked).
So i thought that i create an object and it keeps those values, doesn't overwrite them, but adds new values to previously and was totally puzzled why suddenly it ignores the filter, that's why i tried to "empty" the object by putting delete window.obj;, but it didn't do a thing. 
So what's wrong here? And if there's any tips in general on what i've wrote, would be glad to hear them:)
Thanks!

Comment: Here obj and checkedInputs are not part of the global window object

Comment: Do you have some sample html we could see, perhaps [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputs not sent when is hidden. Its part of standar of HTML.
Form sent inputs only visible objects.

childCount is not defined.

Comment: That's not true. `disabled` inputs are not posted, but `hidden` i.e. `input type='hidden'..` elements are.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean about sent, if you mean that they are not sent to the server, then that's not what i am doing here.
I'm trying to build and object with those inputs and then send it.
Everything works, until i'm trying to build that object from previously been display:none; checkboxes to now(after clicking the link) display:block;. And jQuery sees those inputs, but then the filter is ignored on :checked

Comment: When i'm clicking on a href, i'm also clearing all the checkboxes with the following code: 
$(function(){
       var checked = true;
       $('.custom input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', checked).next().toggleClass('checked', false);
    });

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/startup2013/r8ker/3/
Names are generated and can be random, they are retrieved from server, same with the values and their quantities.
In this example, i need to get the name and all the values that are checked(there can be as many as 100(both names or categories and values in those categories), doesn't matter, as long as i get the corresponding names and the list of values to send to server).

Comment: So that's why i thought about object, which gets all the values in var obj = $('input[type="checkbox"]'); and carry on from there, and afters to send those names, their value/values and on showing other list of checkbox, repeat the process.
So for instance: person chooses from Hawaii: accomodation->Castle,Flat; Outside->Rock,Sand,Water;
Then he clicks on search and those values are sent to the server.

Afters he wants fruits, so he clicks the link, chooses the value or values he wants and it gets sent to the server with another Ajax call.

Comment: Use multiple inputs[] with array formats: http://jsfiddle.net/r8ker/15/ and serialize() function.

Comment: Very neat way to do it, but the problem persists and another two pops up.

1. When the page loads and i click the button, nothing happens. Then when i click the button again, it works from then on,but..

2. Everytime i click the button it mulptiples, for instance, the first time i clicked, it shows once the options that where chosen, second time i click it shows those new options, but twice, third time same, but three times now and so on...

3. Also, the initial problem is the same, when i change links it gives me back all the checkbox list instead of only checked ones.

Comment: What i did, was got rid of Foundation Zurb framework and everything's fine now.
Seems to me that framework gave me more headache through my project, than benefit, so really not worth it if you want to concetrate on app itself.
Thanks for your answers and nice experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to push all the checkboxes into an array, and then store them into a variable like this:

```
    function Bada() {

     var checkboxes= [];
        $('.checkBoxClass').each(function(index){
            checkboxArray.push($(this).data('id'));
        });
        var together = checkBoxArray.join();

        $.ajax({
            url     : '/getItems',
            data    : {
                    'someproperty'      : together
            },
        success : function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
        } ...
```

under the condition that you give the checkboxes some data-id in the markup, and that data-id is not created dynamically. That way, you will get all the checkboxes stored and sent properly along with any other data you may have, here is just an example of what you could try.

I used a similar method when I needed to store multiple checked/unchecked options and send them via AJAX.

Let me know if this was any helpful to you.